# Holes through plumbers box (double header in floor joist)

Tags: plumbing, framing, joists, structural, construction

A joist is right where the drain is for the bathtub and I am looking for a solution to do the plumbing. Currently, the plan is to do a 'Plumbers Box' in the floor joists which solves the initial issue.

Now, I also plan to have the plumbing for the tub run through the joists. Is this still possible or am I now limited?

My joist are 2x10s and 16in on center, the holes through the joists will be 3". They would follow the guidelines defined here. https://www.familyhandyman.com/floor/how-to-drill-through-floor-joists/view-all, however again, not sure if I can still put holes in the double header.

The image below is not what I have, its just to show what I would like to do. Is this possible?

[image]